# Connect And Disconnect Mobile Broadband Connection

Tags: c#, mobile, connection, broadband

Please tell me how to connect and disconnect mobile broadband connection using C# or DOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support in .NET, you need to invoke the win api, specifically `wininet.dll` and invoke [InternetGetConnectedState function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can use the following link for with a sample code. Code is in VB, but you can easily [convert it to c#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/).

- [How to determine the connection state of your local system and how to initiate or end an Internet connection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821770)

Answer (score 5):

On the commandline (DOS) you can use the netsh command.

Instructions:
1) Get the mobile interface and note the name

```
netsh mbn show interface
```

Output:

```
There is 1 interface on the system:

Name               : Mobiel 5
Description        : Sierra Wireless EM7345 4G LTE
GUID               : xxx
Physical Address   : xxx
State              : Not connected
Device type        : Mobile Broadband device is embedded in the system
Cellular class     : GSM
Device Id          : xxx
Manufacturer       : Sierra Wireless Inc.
Model              : Sierra Wireless EM7345 4G LTE
Firmware Version   : FIH7160_V1.2_WW_01.1442.11
Provider Name      : BEL PROXIMUS
Roaming            : Yes
Signal             : 74%
RSSI / RSCP        : 23 (-67 dBm)
```

2) Get the connection profiles for the interface (on my system the name is "mobiel 5"

```
netsh mbn show profiles interface="mobiel 5"
```

Output

```
Profiles on interface Mobiel 5:
-------------------------------------
    {3623E7AB-E116-47E6-8A9B-FCC1ADBE568E}
    {F4E77FAE-D4FD-4196-86CA-852EFE8A9154}
    !!##MBIMModemProvisionedContextInternetProfile##8935299564103228197
```

3) Connect using the interface and profile name

```
netsh mbn connect interface="mobiel 5" connmode=name name="{F4E77FAE-D4FD-4196-86CA-852EFE8A9154}"
```

4) Disconnect using the interface name

```
netsh mbn disconnect interface="mobiel 5"
```

This works on Windows 10