# Connect to Mobile Network on Laptop via Commandline

Tags: command-line, cellular-network

I have a SIM-Card in my Laptop and I want to automate the connection. I have removed the PIN from the SIM-Card. I can disconnect with

```
netsh mbn disconnect interface="Cellular"
```

This works. If I try to connect with

```
netsh mbn connect interface="Cellular"
```

I get an error, that one or more Parameters are wrong for the command.

I'm using a Windows 10 Machine.

Comment: Have you tried the steps from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51632402/8330162 yet?

Comment: @B--rian : Thanks for the link, I've been looking for something like that for a long time! Hey you guys, no upvotes for that well written (and for at least one other person ) helpful answer? C'mon! Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by B--rian I ended up using

```
netsh mbn connect interface="Cellular" connmode=name name="{...}"
```

I had to disable the PIN for this to work.